# libssl.so.6 not found for check_nrpe

Tags: linux, centos, nagios, nrpe

I couldn't get NRPE to work, so I ran it locally and this error popped up:

```
./check_nrpe: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After I check my "check_nrpe" with ldd command, I got this :

```
[root@supervision lib64]# ldd /srv/eyesofnetwork/nagios-3.5.1/plugins/check_nrpe
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7744000)
        libssl.so.6 => not found
        libcrypto.so.6 => not found
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0xf7720000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7562000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7745000)
```

But I'm providing libssl and libcrypto for "6".

```
    [root@supervision lib64]# yum provides /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.6
    Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.in2p3.fr
     * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
     * extras: mirror.in2p3.fr
     * updates: mirror.in2p3.fr
    openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7.centos.3.i686 : A compatibility version of a general cryptography and TLS library
    Dépôt               : base
    Correspondance depuis :
    Nom de fichier : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.6

[root@supervision lib64]# yum provides /usr/lib/libssl.so.6
    Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.in2p3.fr
     * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
     * extras: mirror.in2p3.fr
     * updates: mirror.in2p3.fr
    openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7.centos.3.i686 : A compatibility version of a general cryptography and TLS library
    Dépôt               : base
    Correspondance depuis :
    Nom de fichier : /usr/lib/libssl.so.6
```

I created a symbolic link :

```
[root@supervision lib64]# sudo ln -s /lib64/libssl.10 /lib/libssl.so.6
[root@supervision lib64]# sudo ln -s /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 /lib/libcrypto.so.6
```

But still doesn't work when I launch ldd command; can you help me?

Comment: It sounds like Rami's answer solved your problem; don't forget to indicate so by clicking on the checkmark next to their answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try to run now, after the symlinks were added, "ldconfig" and then again the ldd command. Does this solve your problem?

Rami Rosen

Comment: Hi, i reloaded my nrpe plugins and now it's working ! xD Thank's for your anwser